# Unrecognized configuration section connectionstrings. Trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to connect to a live SQL Server database as opposed to the local one for login authentication. Here are my settings in `web.config`:

```
<connectionstrings>
   <add name="scrumDbConnectionString"
        connectionstring="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;
                          User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD"
        providername="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionstrings>
```

When I am in the website administration tool when I go to the security page I get the following error:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unrecognized configuration section connectionstrings. (C:\Documents and Settings\tunnelld\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\ZSRBlank\web.config line 10)

But when I check the database connection it says its fine. Help!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f3df53fe-666b-4a98-92d2-d6e4ba52552a/unrecognized-configuration-section-connectionstrings

Comment: I just tried setting the target framework from 4.0 to 2.0 and it caused the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the ConnectionString on one line, I think the line feed / space is throwing it off

Comment: Did you try it like this? <connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>          http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config

Comment: I tried to copy and paste what you had and changed the credentials and it was connecting to the local db again.

Comment: Replace server=YOUR_SERVER_NAME

Comment: I recently came across this error myself and changing the target framework from 4.0 to 2.0 resolved the issue.  so I assume this error is the result of running a web site / application with a target framework of 4.0 on an older version of IIS e.g. V 6.0